# TcpClient -> How to retrieve a stream from a sub-directory like http://localhost:8000/admin?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Stream running at this URL: http://localhost:8000/admin
I want to connect to it via a TcpClient, but don't know where I can specify the directory.

currently I do this:

tcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8000);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is the underyling protocol as does not have any concept of the 'directories'.  The portion of the URI that you are talking about is used by the HTTP web-server to specify the web page resource.  In terms of TCP, an HTTP request for `http://localhost:8000/admin` translates to a TCP connection being made to port 8000 on the local host with the following request text:

```
GET /admin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
...
```

(There will be some more request headers than those shown, but those are the basic ones.)

You may wish to switch to using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or somesuch instead.

See [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http).

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a protocol for transmitting data in a stream from one endpoint to another endpoint. An endpoint for TCP is an `(ip-address, port)` pair.

To specify that you want to open a connection with a particular service on a given machine with a known IP address, that service must be listening on a specific known port. Then that combination of known `(ip-address, port)` is the endpoint to connect to.